# How can I use the Retrofit response outside the OnResponse function?

Tags: android, retrofit

I want to get the retrofit response list and use it outside the OnResponse function, but went I try to do it I'm always getting a null object.
Here is my source code

```
ApiInterface apiService = ApiClient.getClient().create(ApiInterface.class);

    Call<ActivitiesResponse> call = apiService.getUserActivities(id);
    call.enqueue(new Callback<ActivitiesResponse>() {
        // If success
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<ActivitiesResponse>call, Response<ActivitiesResponse> response) {

             list = response.body().getActivities();// I'm getting a not null response 

        }
        // If failed
        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<ActivitiesResponse>call, Throwable t) {
            // Log error here since request failed
            Log.e(TAG, t.toString());

        }
    });

    //When I try to use the list here I'm getting a null object
```

Comment: Do what you want in the onResponse, or you will get everytime `NullPointException` because `Callback` is `Asynchrone` so `onResponse` will be call when the request is over.

Comment: try to check the size of the list after you have stored data in it in `onResponse` i think the data is not storing ion the list.

Comment: @RaphaelTeyssandier So I understand that there is no possibility to get my result out side the OnResponse function??

Comment: You might be accessing  the "list" before  retrofit onResponse() call execution. Try using an observer. So that you can notify it anywhere you wish.

Comment: @Anmol The size of the list is not null, I already checked the content of the list and it contain data

Comment: You can, but you can't use it just after calling your request

Answer (score 5):

Requests are async, so when you try to return a value, the request is likely not done yet so you cannot use it outside of the request. If you want to return values from the request use callback interfaces.

Change your code to a method and pass a callback parameter

Example

```
public void doRequest(final ApiCallback callback) {
    ApiInterface apiService = ApiClient.getClient().create(ApiInterface.class);

    Call<ActivitiesResponse> call = apiService.getUserActivities(id);
    call.enqueue(new Callback<ActivitiesResponse>() {
        // If success
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<ActivitiesResponse>call, Response<ActivitiesResponse> response) {

             list = response.body().getActivities();
             callback.onSuccess(list); // pass the list
        }
        // If failed
        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<ActivitiesResponse>call, Throwable t) {
            // Log error here since request failed
            Log.e(TAG, t.toString());
        }
    });
}

public interface ApiCallback{
    void onSuccess(ArrayList<YOURTYPE> result);
}
```

Example usage in onResume(), basically you can do this anywhere you want:

```
public void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    doRequest(new ApiCallback(){
         @Override
         public void onSuccess(ArrayList<YOURTYPE> result){
             //do stuff here with the list from the request
         }
    });
}
```

Let me know if this fits your needs

Comment: Thank you for your answer I will give a try

Answer (score 0):

Because onResponse() runs asynchronously. You can not get its value like that.
You should call the method which uses `list` value inside onResponse(). 
For example.

```
 call.enqueue(new Callback<ActivitiesResponse>() {
        // If success
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<ActivitiesResponse>call, Response<ActivitiesResponse> response) {

             list = response.body().getActivities();// I'm getting a not null response 
             yourMethod();
        }
        // If failed
        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<ActivitiesResponse>call, Throwable t) {
            // Log error here since request failed
            Log.e(TAG, t.toString());

        }
    });

  private void yourMethod() {
     //  list is used somewhere here
  }
```

Comment: Glad it helps. If it works for you, please accept the answer. Thanks.