# How can I use the Retrofit response outside the OnResponse function so I can return it up the recommended architecture model?

Tags: java, android, callback

This question follows on from [How can I use the Retrofit response outside the OnResponse function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44042582/how-can-i-use-the-retrofit-response-outside-the-onresponse-function?rq=1), but I'm not allowed to comment, so I'm asking it for myself here.

I'm trying to use the Android Studio Login template because it follows the recommended architecture, but I'm having trouble returning the Result in LoginDataSource.login. The result is trapped in the Call.enqueue function and I can't get it out to return. I've reproduced the callback suggested in the above link, but that just traps the result in a new class.

How can I access the LoggedInUser returned by my server to return to my repository?

Original attempt: user is stuck in Call.enqueue - onResponse

```
public class LoginDataSource {
    public static Retrofit retrofit = null;
    LoggedInUser user;

    public Result<LoggedInUser> login(String username, String password) {
        user = new LoggedInUser();
        try {
            // TODO: handle loggedInUser authentication
            retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl("https://myserver")
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .build();
            PostEndPoint endPoint = retrofit.create(PostEndPoint.class);
            Call<LoggedInUser> call = endPoint.getUser("login", username, password);

            call.enqueue(new Callback<LoggedInUser>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call<LoggedInUser> call, Response<LoggedInUser> response) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "onResponse: code " + response.code());
                    if (response.isSuccessful()){
                        callback.getUser();
                        user = response.body();
                        Log.d(TAG, "onResponse: " + user); // this returns valid user data
                    }
                }
            });

            Log.d(TAG, "retrofit complete:" + user.getName()); // this returns null

            return new Result.Success<>(user);
        }
    }
}
```

And after implementing callback: user is stuck in GetUserResponse - getUser

```
public class LoginDataSource {
    public static Retrofit retrofit = null;
    LoggedInUser user;

    public Result<LoggedInUser> login(String username, String password) {
        user = new LoggedInUser();
        try {
            // TODO: handle loggedInUser authentication
                retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                        .baseUrl("https://myserver")
                        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                        .build();
                PostEndPoint endPoint = retrofit.create(PostEndPoint.class);
                Call<LoggedInUser> call = endPoint.getUser("login", username, password);

                sendLoginRequest(call, new GetUserResponse(){
                    @Override
                    public void getUser(LoggedInUser userFromResponse) {
                        user = userFromResponse;
                    }
                });
                Log.d(TAG, "retrofit complete:" + user.getName()); // this returns null

            return new Result.Success<>(user);
        }
    }

    private void sendLoginRequest (Call call, final GetUserResponse callback) {
        call.enqueue(new Callback<LoggedInUser>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<LoggedInUser> call, Response<LoggedInUser> response) {
                if (response.isSuccessful()){
                    callback.getUser(response.body());
                }
            }
        });
    }
}

public interface GetUserResponse {
    void getUser(LoggedInUser user);
}
```

I feel like I need to have sendLoginRequest return the user, but I can't work out how to do that. Am I heading in the right direction? Any advice is welcome.

Comment: if you know LiveData  and Hilt ,you can get your retrofit instance in repository class using dependency injection .Then you can send request from repository class then  set your response to Livedata.If Any Activity class observing live data will get live result.

Comment: I don't understand much of what you said, but it gives me something to read up on. Thanks.

Comment: It took me a while to go through everything. Finding the full set of codelabs made a big difference. Hilt makes dependency injection easier, but it wasn't required for the solution. Making LoggedInUser a LiveData variable, updating it from the retrofit thread using LoggedInUser.postValue(user) and then observing the LoggedInUser from the viewmodel was the answer, though it meant changing the provided base code. I also switched to Kotlin along the way so I'm not exactly sure how to answer my own question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I switched to Kotlin along the way, so this may not be correct Java, but it shows the process

1. Set the user model as [LiveData](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/livedata)
2. update the user model using [.postValue()](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/livedata#update_livedata_objects)
3. set up an [observer](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/livedata#observe_livedata_objects) for the user model in the viewmodel (not shown)

```
public class LoginDataSource {
    public static Retrofit retrofit = null;
    MutableLiveData<LoggedInUser> user=new MutableLiveData<>(); // changed this to LiveData so it can be observed from the viewmodel

    public Result<LoggedInUser> login(String username, String password) {
        user = new LoggedInUser();
        try {
            // TODO: handle loggedInUser authentication
            retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl("https://myserver")
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .build();
            PostEndPoint endPoint = retrofit.create(PostEndPoint.class);
            loggedInUser = endPoint.getUser("login", username, password);
            user.postValue(loggedInUser); // updated the livedata here
        }
    }
}
```